# Undefined name 'items'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

Before I made listview can display data normally but I added search bar to make it more user friendly but I got a problem.
Undefined name 'items'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.   and  Undefined name 'duplicateItems'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
`your text`
Code
`class view_problem extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<view_problem> createState() => _view_problemState();
}

```
     class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
       List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
       StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
       Future getAllProblem() async {
       problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
      _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
    }

    @override
      void initState() {
      // TODO: implement initState
       Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        getAllProblem();
      });
      super.initState();
    }

     void _filterSearch(String query) {
       setState(() {
          items = duplicateItems
         .where((item) => item.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
         .toList();
    });
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 12, 134),
        title: const Text('show'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
         children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _filterSearch(value),
               decoration: const InputDecoration(
                 labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
           const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
               child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshots) {
                  if (snapshots.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: problemlist.length,
                         itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                          return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                problem.name_surname,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                problem.address,
                               style: TextStyle(
                                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                             ),
                               trailing: Text(
                                problem.status,
                               style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                             ),
                           ),
                         );
                       }));
                       }
                     return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                   );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

Comment: shouldn't `items` just be `problemList`?

Comment: duplicateItems also error